# CSS selector :target not working?

Tags: html, css, noscript

I am trying to create a warning for my website that is only being displayed when JavaScript is disabled. This warning should be able to be "clicked away". To achieve this, I thought the CSS selector `:target` might be a good idea. I eventually came up with the code that can be seen at the bottom of this post.

The idea of this snippet was that the user has to click the link in order to let the warning disappear. Since CSS offers the `:target` selector and I am able to target a `<div>` element by a link, I thought this might work out. Well, apparently it doesn't. I also tried it with the same code on my [homepage](http://mezzodrinker.info/) but as you might notice, it doesn't work there either.

I greatly appreciate any help that might help me get this thing done.

```css
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800");

/********************/
/* noscript warning */
/********************/
div.noscript-warning {
    opacity: 1;
    background: #6ee5f9;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0.2em;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    text-align: right;
    animation-duration: 2s, 2s;
    animation-delay: 0s, 2s;
    animation-timing-function: none, ease-in-out;
    animation-name: hide, fade-in;
}

div.noscript-warning > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

div.noscript-warning-text {
    padding: 0.2em;
    border: solid white 0.2em;
    text-align: center;
}

#hide-warning { display: none; }
#hide-warning:target + div.noscript-warning { display: none; }
@keyframes hide { from { opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 0; } }
@keyframes fade-in { from { opacity: 0; color: #6ee5f9; } to { opacity: 1; color: #fff; } }
```

```html
<div class="noscript-warning">
    <div id="hide-warning"></div>
    <div class="noscript-warning-text">
        This page makes use of JavaScript to display certain aesthetic goodies. These are disabled because you have JavaScript disabled. Because of that, certain features will not work at all. You have been warned.<br/>
        Click &quot;Dismiss&quot; to dismiss this warning.
    </div>
    <a href="#hide-warning">Dismiss [x]</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you wrote

```
#hide-warning:target + div.noscript-warning { display: none; }
```

but the sibling div of `#hide-warning` has class `.noscript-warning-text` so the selector should be

```
#hide-warning:target + div.noscript-warning-text { display: none; }
```

if you need instead to select the outer div, just move `#hide-warning` one level up, e.g.

```
<div id="hide-warning"></div>
<div class="noscript-warning">
    <div class="noscript-warning-text">
      ... 
</div>
```

Or, if you prefer to avoid a useless empty `div` and clean a bit your markup you could write

```
<div id="hide-warning" class="noscript-warning">
    <div class="noscript-warning-text">
      ... 
</div>
```

so your selector simply becomes

```
 #hide-warning:target { display: none; }
```

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to not only hide the text but the whole div that contains the warning so writing ```div.noscript-warning``` was definitely intended.

Comment: but .noscript-warning is its parent so you cannot select it via `+`adjacent selector